# Remove subcategory in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. I use in my project Laravel 5.8.

I have this code:

Model:

```
class ProductsCategory extends Model
{
    protected $quarded = [];
    protected $fillable = ['company_id', 'enable', 'name', 'url_address', 'level', 'parent_id', 'number'];
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $table = 'products_category';
}
```

Migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products_category', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->char('enable', 1)->default(0);
            $table->string('name', 85)->nullable();
            $table->string('url_address', 160);
            $table->integer('level')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('parent_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('number')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
        });
    }
```

I have many categories and subcategories in the database.
Subcategories and categories are connected by parent_id.

How can I delete a record in such a way that all its subcategories are removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the relation in your database and set the subcategories to be removed when the parent category is removed.

In your migration:

```
$table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('products_category')->onDelete('cascade');
```

---

**Update:** You should remove the `->default(0);` from the `parent_id` defenition. I don't supose you have a category with id `0`. Just make the column nullabel by adding `->nullable();`.

**Update:** All increments (`increments`, `bigIncrement`, ...) in laravel are `unsigned` integers of different sizes.
So you need to declare an `unsignedBigInterger` for it to have the same type as the primary key you are referencing.

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
```

just like you did with `company_id`

```
$table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
```

Comment: I have error:  Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `products_category` add constraint `products_category_parent_id_foreign` foreign key (`parent_id`) references `products_category` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: I have: $table->bigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('products_category')->onDelete('cascade'); - and error: Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `products_category` add constraint `products_category_parent_id_foreign` foreign key (`parent_id`) references `products_category` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: Do you already have any `parent_id`s in your table that do not exist in the categories table?

Comment: change `$table->bigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();` to `$table->bigUnsignedInteger('parent_id')->nullable();` all Increments field type are unsigned

Comment: Now I have error:  BadMethodCallException  : Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::bigUnsignedInteger does not exist.

Comment: @goslscs sorry, the method is actually `unsignedBigInteger` you can check it here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#creating-columns you can also find on that link that increments are unsigned

Comment: Now migrations run ok. When I add new record I have error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`products_category`, CONSTRAINT `products_category_parent_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `products_category` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `products_category` (`company_id`, `enable`, `name`, `url_address`, `level`, `parent_id`, `number`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 0, 11, 11, 0, 0, 1, 2019-08-08 10:49:33, 2019-08-08 10:49:33))

Comment: you need to change the `0` for parent_id when there is no parent to `null` when you add a new parent category. Or put a valid `id` if it's a child

Answer (score 0):

just exactly set the same way the foreign key on company_id, but reference it to the primary key of products_category in this line, and also change the default 0 into nullable, so it won't break relationship

```
$table->bigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
$table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('products_category')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: I make this code: Schema::create('products_category', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
.........
            $table->bigInteger('parent_id')->default(0);
            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('products_category')->onDelete('cascade')
        });

Comment: but I have error:   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `products_category` add constraint `products_category_parent_id_foreign` foreign key (`parent_id`) references `products_category` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: its because there's no 0 id existed in your table,
you should just make it nullable instead of default 0 since it would break any relationship

Comment: It's not help. My full code: Yes, I have. This is my full code: https://pastebin.com/mzLvzsne . I have error:  Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `products_category` add constraint `products_category_parent_id_foreign` foreign key (`parent_id`) references `products_category` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: actually you really need to understanding concept of database relationship, thats the only thing you lack on